# Radius of a circumference having two chords

Tags: geometry, circles

In the image, the lenghts of the chords are $6$ and $8$, and the gap between the chords is $1$. Then the radius of the circumference is?

[image]

I drew the perpendicular diameters to the chords and tried to apply power of a point, but i didn't find anything. I need some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Pythagoras,

$$\sqrt{r^2-3^2}-\sqrt{r^2-4^2}=1$$

then

$$(r^2-3^2)-2\sqrt{r^2-3^2}\sqrt{r^2-4^2}+(r^2-4^2)=1,$$

$$(2r^2-26)^2=4(r^2-9)(r^2-16),$$

$$4r^2-100=0.$$